# Force build to top of queue when triggered

Tags: teamcity, teamcity-7.1

I have a single agent and many builds. There are frequently several builds in the queue that take an hour a piece to execute. I want to trigger daily at a specific time a build which takes less than five seconds but needs to run immediately (next in the queue). Is there any way to do this?

Build priorities are suggested in various places but they do not help. I set the priority to the max value of 100 and it was placed at 15 out of 17 in the queue.

Comment: Does it depend on anything?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Nope, it is triggered every day at 6pm no matter what.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working around the problem and moving this build to another practically dedicated teamcity agent which means this executes promptly. This is not a good solution and I would prefer to accept an actual answer if anyone is able to offer one.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Teamcity REST](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD9/REST+API#RESTAPI-TriggeringaBuild) to trigger the build and put on top of the queue. You can make use of triggering option `queueAtTop="true"`

Comment: I notice that is documentation for Teamcity 9.X. I checked the 7.X documentation and didn't find a similar option. Also, I'd really like not to have to code a separate tool for triggering this one build. Unless you can point me to that feature for 7.X, I can't accept this answer. Sorry.